# How do I do a Fulton Recover of a solider on a ledge above me?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-hd-collection, metal-gear-solid-peace-walker

In *Metal Gear Sold: Peace Walker HD* there are sometimes soldiers on ledges above me. I tranq them but I can't get them to fall down nor am I able to get up to them. How do I do a Fulton Recovery of them? Or are they just put there to tease me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I need some [very advanced equipment](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Peace_Walker_weapons_and_equipment) to do this:

- `Tanegashima Musket` [GMP 330900, R&D 89] - Rathalos Wing and Japanese Patriot (Extra Ops 049) → Complete Extra Ops 121 and 122 + Japanese Patriot/Extra Ops 049
- `Carl Gustav M2 (Fulton)` Rank 3 [GMP 294260, R&D 74, MDC 56, INT 67] - Carl Gustav M2 (Fulton) Design Specs → Complete Extra Ops 098
- `Fulton Sleep Gas Mine` Rank 5 [GMP 289720, R&D 62, MDC 52, INT 63] - Fulton Sleep Gas Mine Design Specs → Complete Extra Ops 064

So mid to high levels of R&D are needed to make most of the equipment as well as having completed certain Extra Ops. And money. Sooo much money.

The Fulton Sleep Gas Mine is likely the first item to be acquired. One you have it, to get someone on a ledge you need to place the mine below them, move a safe distance away, then shoot it with any gun (even the Mk.22) and it will trip and catch anyone above it.

The Carl Gustav M2 (Fulton) is very loud and will trigger a response from any troops in the area, so it should only be used on the last guy.

Answer (score 0):

If you say the soldiers are on a ledge (hopefully they're not too far up) you could go into your item menu, (make sure you have the love box equipped) press "L" to drop the box, then run into the box and climb on top of the box, then run in front of the ledge and get on top of the ledge.

Comment: They are much too high for that.